# MSSQL - Delete duplicate rows using common column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't used SQL in quite a while, so I'm a bit lost here. I wanted to check for rows with duplicate values in the "Duration" and "date" columns to remove them from the query results. I would need to keep the rows where column = "Transfer" since these hold more information about the call and how it was routed through our system.

I want to use this for a dashboard, which would include counting the total number of calls from that query, which is why I cannot have both.

Here's the (Simplified) code used:

```sql
SELECT status, user, duration, phonenumber, date
FROM (SELECT * FROM view_InboundPhoneCalls) as Phonecalls
WHERE date>=DATEADD(dd, -15, getdate())
--GROUP BY duration
```

Which gives something of the sort:

| Status | User | Duration | phonenumber | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Received | Receptionnist | 00:34:03 | from: +1234567890 | 2021-09-30 16:01:57 |
| Received | Receptionnist | 00:03:12 | from: +9876543210 | 2021-09-30 16:02:40 |
| **Transfer** | **User1** | **00:05:12** | **+*14161654965*;Receptionnist;User1** | **2021-09-30 16:01:57** |
| **Received** | **Receptionnist** | **00:05:12** | **from: *+14161654965*** | **2021-09-30 16:01:57** |

The end result would be something like this:

| Status | User | Duration | phonenumber | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Received | Receptionnist | 00:34:03 | from: +1234567890 | 2021-09-30 16:01:57 |
| Received | Receptionnist | 00:03:12 | from: +9876543210 | 2021-09-30 16:02:40 |
| **Transfer** | **Receptionnist** | **00:05:12** | **+*14161654965*;Receptionnist;User1** | **2021-09-30 16:01:57** |

Comment: So you want to ignore duplicated rows in your query - there is no deletion?

Comment: Sortoff yes, I would use deletions but the actual table is updated from a very un-user friendly .txt. file from our 3CX phone system. There might be a way to update the view itself to remove these rows, but I don't think it'd be feasible to delete the rows from the table, because of the way the devs convert the txt file to data that can be put in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal "trick" is to detect duplicates first. One of the easier ways is a CTE (Common Table Expression) along with the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Part One - Mark the duplicates

```
WITH
  cte_Sorted_List
(
  status, usertype, duration, phonenumber, dated, duplicate_check
)
AS
( -- only use required fields to speed up
  SELECT  status, user, duration, phonenumber, date,
    -- marks depend on correct columns!
    Row_Number() OVER 
    ( -- sort over relevant columns to show
      PARTITION BY user, phonenumber, date, duration
      -- with correct sort order 
      -- bit of hack: As T comes after R
      -- logic: mark records to show as row number 1 in duplicate list
      ORDER BY status DESC
    ) AS duplicate_check
  FROM    view_InboundPhoneCalls
  -- and lose all unnecessary data
  WHERE   date>=DATEADD(dd, -15, getdate())
)
```

Part two - show relevant rows

```
SELECT
  status, usertype, duration, phonenumber, dated
FROM
  cte_Sorted_List
WHERE
  Duplicate_Check = 1
;
```

First CTE extracts required fields in single pass, then that data only is used for output.

Comment: You need to remove `User` and `phonenumber` from the partitioning, based on the example. Also `User` is a reserved word and needs escaping `[User]`. And columns not selected in the final output will be pruned all the way down, so don't worry about that.

Comment: This with @Charlieface 's answer seems to have worked. Both your answers were very similar, but I think this one took care of the cases where there were more than 2 repeating entries. It took me a while to mark as answer since there was something wrong with the phone system's CDR. It does what it should do! I could never have found that by my own! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a blacklist, say with a CTE, then filter out the undesired rows.

Something like:

```
WITH Blacklist ([date], [duration]) AS (
    SELECT [date], [duration] FROM view_InboundPhoneCalls
    GROUP BY [date], [duration] 
    Having count(*) > 1
)

SELECT status, user, duration, phonenumber, date
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM view_InboundPhoneCalls) as Phonecalls
LEFT JOIN 
    Blacklist
ON Phonecalls.[date] = Blacklist.[date]
AND Phonecalls.[duration] = Blacklist.[duration]

Where 
    Blacklist.[date] is null
Or
    (Blacklist.[date] is not null AND Phonecalls.[Status] == 'Transfer')
```

Comment: I seemed to have trouble with this, for some reason Grafana didn't know how to use it correctly, but it seemed to work in SQL. I will try this and other solutions to see which works best. Thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use row-numbering for this, along with a custom ordering. There is no need for any joins.

```sql
SELECT status, [user], duration, phonenumber, date
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY duration, date
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'Transfer' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
    FROM view_InboundPhoneCalls
    WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, -15, getdate())
) as Phonecalls
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I might have to test it more on my side, but it seems to be working as it should :)

Comment: It seems to work intermittently, what I hadn't accounted for is cases where there seems to be 3 or 4 rows with the same duration and date but alternating between status "Received" and "Transfer" (for inbound calls). That might be happening because there can be multiple transfers and the phone system uses only the initial call time. I will continue testing this and other answers!

Comment: You need to finesse the partitioning clause to get the rows to group correctly